# Row pairs with no overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have line items from an order, some of which are on a *Buy one get one free* offer. The business logic for this is:

- The cheapest item of a pair is free
- The best deal for the customer is selected
- Once an item has been used in an offer it can't be used again

Here is an example of some line items (`OrderItemID`) which have been joined to all of their offers.

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ OrderItemID ║ OfferID ║ Value ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ 1           ║ 1       ║ 22.50 ║
║ 2           ║ 1       ║ 25.00 ║
║ 3           ║ 2       ║ 14.99 ║
║ 4           ║ 1       ║ 5.00  ║
║ 5           ║ 1       ║ 7.00  ║
║ 5           ║ 2       ║ 7.00  ║
║ 5           ║ 3       ║ 7.00  ║
║ 6           ║ 3       ║ 7.50  ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

From this I can derive the full set of valid combinations using the rules above, ordered by the saving (i.e. price of the second item):

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ PaidOrderItemID ║ FreeOrderItemID ║ OfferID ║ Price ║ Saving ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 2               ║ 1               ║ 1       ║ 25.00 ║ 22.50  ║
║ 1               ║ 5               ║ 1       ║ 22.50 ║ 7.00   ║
║ 2               ║ 5               ║ 1       ║ 25.00 ║ 7.00   ║
║ 3               ║ 5               ║ 2       ║ 14.99 ║ 7.00   ║
║ 6               ║ 5               ║ 3       ║ 7.50  ║ 7.00   ║
║ 1               ║ 4               ║ 1       ║ 22.50 ║ 5.00   ║
║ 2               ║ 4               ║ 1       ║ 25.00 ║ 5.00   ║
║ 5               ║ 4               ║ 1       ║ 7.00  ║ 5.00   ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

I now want to extract the combinations, without overlap in the order items. The following table shows what I need

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ PaidOrderItemID ║ FreeOrderItemID ║ OfferID ║ Price ║ Saving ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 2               ║ 1               ║ 1       ║ 25.00 ║ 22.50  ║
║ 3               ║ 5               ║ 2       ║ 14.99 ║ 7.00   ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

The first row is the one with the highest saving. 
The next row is the first row where `PaidOrderItemID` and `FreeOrderItemID` are different to the `ItemID`s used in the first row.

I have this working using cursor to extract a the top row to a temp table, then remove offers using the same `OrderItemID`s, repeating until no offers remain.

I'd like to know if there is a way it can be done using a set based method? I have tried using a recursive CTE approach with no luck. The code needs to run on SQL Server 2008 R2.

The code for the example is below:

```
DECLARE @orderItemOffers TABLE (OrderItemID INT, OfferID INT, Value MONEY)
INSERT INTO @orderItemOffers
        (OrderItemID, OfferID, Value)
VALUES  (1, 1, 22.50),
        (2, 1, 25.00),
        (3, 2, 14.99),
        (4, 1, 5.00),
        (5, 1, 7.00),
        (5, 2, 7.00),
        (5, 3, 7.00),
        (6, 3, 7.50)

SELECT * FROM @orderItemOffers

DECLARE @offerCombos TABLE (
    PaidOrderItemID INT,
    FreeOrderItemID INT,
    OfferID INT,
    Price MONEY,
    Saving MONEY
)
INSERT INTO @offerCombos (
    PaidOrderItemID,
    FreeOrderItemID,
    OfferID,
    Price,
    Saving
)
SELECT PaidItem.OrderItemID,
       FreeItem.OrderItemID,
       FreeItem.OfferID,
       PaidItem.Value,
       FreeItem.Value
FROM @orderItemOffers PaidItem
INNER JOIN @orderItemOffers FreeItem
    ON FreeItem.OrderItemID <> PaidItem.OrderItemID
       AND FreeItem.OfferID = PaidItem.OfferID
       AND (FreeItem.Value < PaidItem.Value 
            OR (FreeItem.Value = PaidItem.Value
                AND FreeItem.OrderItemID > PaidItem.OrderItemID
               )
           )
ORDER BY FreeItem.Value DESC

SELECT * FROM @offerCombos

DECLARE @takenOffers TABLE (
    PaidOrderItemID INT,
    FreeOrderItemID INT,
    OfferID INT,
    Price MONEY,
    Saving MONEY
)
DECLARE offerCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT * FROM @offerCombos
OPEN offerCursor

DECLARE @PaidOrderItemID INT, @FreeOrderItemID INT,
        @OfferID INT, @Price MONEY, @Saving MONEY
FETCH NEXT FROM offerCursor
INTO @PaidOrderItemID, @FreeOrderItemID, @OfferID, @Price, @Saving

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @takenOffers
           (PaidOrderItemID, FreeOrderItemID, OfferID, Price, Saving)
    VALUES (@PaidOrderItemID, @FreeOrderItemID, @OfferID, @Price, @Saving)

    DELETE FROM @offerCombos
    WHERE PaidOrderItemID IN (@PaidOrderItemID, @FreeOrderItemID)
       OR FreeOrderItemID IN (@PaidOrderItemID, @FreeOrderItemID)

    FETCH NEXT FROM offerCursor
    INTO @PaidOrderItemID, @FreeOrderItemID, @OfferID, @Price, @Saving
END 

CLOSE offerCursor
DEALLOCATE offerCursor

SELECT * FROM @takenOffers
```

Comment: there is no such thing as first row without describing what to order by

Comment: The rows must be in descending order using the lowest price item of the pair used in the offer.

Answer (score 0):

You may start with somehting like this

```
WITH Offer AS (
SELECT *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OfferID ORDER BY Value DESC)
FROM @orderItemOffers
)
SELECT 
    o1.OrderItemID AS PaidOrderItemID 
    ,o2.OrderItemID AS FreeOrderItemID
    ,o1.OfferID
    ,o1.Value AS Price
    , o2.Value as Saving
FROM Offer o1
LEFT JOIN Offer o2 
    ON o1.OfferID = o2.OfferID
    AND o1.rn = o2.rn -1
WHERE o1.rn % 2 = 1
ORDER BY OfferID,PaidOrderItemID
```

***<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2bc4/1)</kbd>***

Comment: This gives the unique pairs in for each offer, but once an item has been used in one offer, it can't be used again in another.

Comment: In the example, Items 1 & 2 are paired using offer 1 with a saving of 22.50. 
Then items 4 & 5 can be paired using offer 1 making a saving of 5.00, but item 5 could also be used for offer 3 with item 6 making a saving of 7.00, as in the 3rd table. After that there are no more pairs in any offer which use items not already used in an offer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OfferID ORDER BY Value DESC, OrderItemID) - 1) % 2 IsFree
FROM @orderItemOffers
```

Within an offer, number the items in descending order by value; every other item is free since it is the next highest value.